# Cmake error undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I make a test for cmake FindThreads. Here is my source code test.cpp and CMakeLists.txt:

```
#include <pthread.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
void* test_func(void* data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  return data;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
int main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  pthread_t thread;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                             
  pthread_detach(thread);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  pthread_cancel(thread);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  pthread_exit(NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
project(test C CXX)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD ON)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
add_executable(test test.cpp)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
if(TARGET Threads::Threads)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE Threads::Threads)                                                                                                                                                                                        
endif()
```

when I run:

```
cmake .
```

I get the outpu:

```
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
```

then I check CMakeError.txt, find that:

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/hye/tmp/cmake-error/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                                                                                                                                                  
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/src.c.o                                                                                                                                                                                           
/usr/bin/clang   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/hye/tmp/cmake-error/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c                                                                                                    
Linking C executable cmTC_55ab6                                                                                                                                                                                                               
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1                                                                                                                                                            
/usr/bin/clang  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_55ab6                                                                                                                                                 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':                                                                                                                                                                           
src.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `pthread_create'                                                                                                                                                                                   
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'                                                                                                                                                                      
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'                                                                                                                                                                      
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `pthread_join'                                                                                                                                                                        
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                                                                                                                                                             
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_55ab6.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_55ab6] Error 1                                                                                                                                                                  
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hye/tmp/cmake-error/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                                                                                                                                                   
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_55ab6/fast] Error 2
```

My question is why performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed, and since it failed, did it
really find Threads, I am totally confused. Thanks for any replying!

Comment: Where is src.c in your CMake file? And where in your CMake file is this `cmTC_55ab6` target mentioned in the make output? The output doesn't seem to match your CMake code...

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks for your reply, these files are temporary files, they are generated by cmake find_packge, the error message generated by find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

Comment: Basically, I copy the C test code in FindThreads.cmake to do this test. my cmake version is 3.17.4, system Fedora 31

Answer (score 3):

There is a little reason to examine `CMakeError.txt` until CMake reports about not-working compiler or CMake reports about unavailable feature, which is detected by probe compilation/linking, but you **expect** that feature to be available.

In your case you have successful CMake configuration (look at the last lines in CMake output), and you have successfully detected Threads-related library(see below). No reasons to worry and no reasons to look into `CMakeError.txt`.

> did it really find Threads?

Yes, Threads are **found**. E.g., CMake clearly states

```
-- Found Threads: TRUE
```

Other ways for deduce, that Threads has been found:

1. You use `REQUIRED` keyword with `find_package(Threads)`. Would Threads not found, CMake will report about an error and terminate configuration.
2. You may check `Threads_FOUND` variable after the `find_package(Threads)` call. (With `REQUIRED` keyword this check is redudant).
3. You may check `Threads::Threads` target after the `find_package(Threads)` call. (With `REQUIRED` keyword this check is redudant).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you give me more details about cmake, you and @fdk1342 help me a lot. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`FindThreads.cmake` tries it best to determine if the compiler supports `pthreads` as a library, a compile time switch, or a link time switch, etcetera.

The failure you are seeing is if a `pthreads` library exists.  It doesn't.  Instead you are supposed to compile the files with `-pthreads` which is a compile time switch your compiler does accept.  This is align with the `clang` documentation which shows that  `-pthreads` is a compiler option, not a linker option.  https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#compilation-flags

So, did it find Threads? Not exactly, there is nothing to find.  Did it determine how to use pthreads? Yes.

You didn't show any errors when building the target `test` with `test.cpp`.  You only posted errors one would expect when `pthreads` is not implemented as a separate library.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so you mean, in compile time it failed, but in link time, it succeed, and -pthread is a compile time, so I should add a compile flag, in fact there are not any errors when building the target test with test.cpp. That's why I am confused, it did have errors when cmake builds.

Comment: I try to add a compile flag, it works, the error is gone! You let me know Clang's flags are different from gcc's which I never think about before. Thank your very much